# Select corresponding value from second table (Mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql

Struggling with some sql, would appreciate some guidance.

Have two tables logs and sense

logs –

```
assetid        ts       nodeid  status

1   2017-10-26 14:00:10    73   240
2   2017-10-26 14:00:06    21   160
3   2017-10-26 14:00:04    18   230
4   2017-10-26 14:00:02    19   400
5   2017-10-26 14:00:00    21   190
1   2017-10-26 13:20:08    18   20
2   2017-10-26 13:06:10    20   160
3   2017-10-26 13:03:04    17   230
```

sense –

```
status  value
20      5
160     37
190     39
230     56
240     58
400     90
```

Trying to find the correct syntax to only show the latest record (in datetime) of each assetid and then show the corresponding value from the sense table (based on the matching status in both tables) to produce –

```
assetid       ts         nodeid     status  value

1   2017-10-26 14:00:10    73        240    58
2   2017-10-26 14:00:06    21        160    37
3   2017-10-26 14:00:04    18        230    56
4   2017-10-26 14:00:02    19        400    90
5   2017-10-26 14:00:00    21        190    39
```

Have tried –

```
Select assetid, ts, nodeid, status, value
From
logs
Join sense X on X.status = logs.status
Group by assetid
Order by ts DESC
```

But this only outputs 1 row  (instead of 5)

```
 assetid          ts      nodeid   status   value

1   2017-10-26 14:00:10    73        240    58
```

Removing

```
Join sense X on X.status = logs.status
```

of course outputs all records but that is not required.

Thoughts appreciated.

Regards

Active

Comment: If any of the the answers below has solved your problem then mark it as the answer and may uupvote it. If not, then kindly comment the remaining issue below the useful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your query is returning 5 rows, 1 for each id. But it won't return rows with latest ts for each id. You can verify this by clicking on the link for demo. You can compare results of both queries.

To achieve this task,following query will help you:

```
Select l.assetid, l.ts, logs.nodeid, X.status, X.value
From
logs
inner Join sense X on X.status = logs.status
inner join (select assetid, max(ts) as ts from logs group by assetid) l
on l.assetid = logs.assetid and logs.ts = l.ts
Group by l.assetid
Order by l.ts DESC;
```

[Click here for Demo](http://rextester.com/ILCN17720)

**EDIT:**

If dataype of `ts` is string then replace `max(ts)` in above query with:

```
max(str_to_date(ts,'%d%m%y'))
```

Feel free to ask any doubts.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Harshil but only returns 1 row (same row as my attempt)

Comment: Are you running this query stand-alone or is this a part of another query? coz you can check the demo. It clearly returns all the required rows.

Comment: Are you using `limit 1` somewhere in your query?

Comment: Running stand-alone, though there are other columns in both tables they are not being referenced. I am using a very old MySQL. Harshil, your example runs in your test window but only returns 1 row when  attempt it

Comment: Query should work on any version of MySQL. Please add the other columns in your question. or create a sqlfiddle of your data and notify here.

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` to find minimum for each assetid and then `JOIN` with the `logs` and `sense`

```
 Select *
 FROM logs l
 JOIN sense s ON s.status = l.status
 JOIN 
 (
  Select assetid, max(ts) maxts
  From logs
  Group by assetid
 ) t ON t.assetid = l.assetid and l.ts = t.maxts
```

[demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=ab15b44ec81a0a2545714f7eeaeaf6a5)

Comment: Thanks Radim Baca but doesn't return any rows

Comment: @Active and the subquery does?

Comment: No rows, there may be an issue with MySQL and mints

Comment: @Active what is the data type of `ts`?

Comment: @active as you can see in the demo, it is working. Problem is in your data.

Comment: Baca ts is datetime

Comment: You don't want '*' here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select a1.assetid, MAX(a1.ts), a1.nodeid, a1.status, X.value
From
logs a1
inner join sense X on X.status = a1.status
Group by assetid, a1.nodeid, a1.status, X.value
Order by ts DESC
```

Comment: Thanks shockwave. but only returns 1 row (same row as my attempt)

Answer (score 0):

On MY SQL 8.0.2

```
WITH CTE as 
(
Select A.assetid, A.ts, A.nodeid, A.status, B.value, row_number() over(PARTITION BY A.assetid ORDER BY A.ts DESC) AS rn
from logs as A
inner join sense B ON A.status=B.status
)

SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE rn='1';
```